# Magento 2.0 weird screen when adding a product

Tags: products, magento-2.0.7

We started a shop in Magento 2.0 but when adding a product we are getting a strange screen.  What is going wrong ? [image: Add a productscreen]

Comment: Have your page is working or not using below solutions?

Comment: I just got the message. Remove the whole directory ? There is a lot in it

Comment: Is not working, still the same screen

Answer (score 1):

You have to run deploy command.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Remove var folder from root.

Clear your browser cache and try again